# 16 bit logical address to 16 bit physical address

Tags: unix, operating-system, addressing

I'm studying for finals. I am studying this question:

Convert the following 16-bit logical address into the 16-bit physical address given
the 6-bit page number and 10-bit offset. Use the supplied process page table.

Logical Address 0000010111011110.

How do I calculate the physical address.

My professor gave us the answer = 0001100111011110  but I do not know how she calculate this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take the top 6 bits, and use its value as an index into your process page table.  In this case, the top 6 bits evaluate to 1, so you replace those bits with the value in entry 1: 000110.

Comment: Yes but how do I map the first 6 bits:

Comment: This is the table : 0 00101  1 000110 2 011001. The correct answer seems to be to use not 1 000110 but I dont know why?

Comment: Without knowing what the "supplied process page table" is, I can't help you.

Comment: I just gave it to you